# colored citations in \section

Tags: beamer, sectioning, citing

I am trying to put in a citation on a section heading using opaline style (yes, I know some think this is a bad idea, but let us leave that aside for now). If I put in

```
\section{Section Heading \citep{...}}
```

everything is fine. However, if I put

```
\section{Section Heading \textcolor{...}{\cite{...}}}
```

then I get an error:

```
...
Argument of \
@gobble has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1 ... \textcolor{Magenta!50}{\citep{Li:2013uq}}}
```

I also tried

```
\section{Section Heading} \section{Section Heading \textcolor{...}{\cite{...}}
```

in which case it moves the citation to the beginning of the next page.

Is there a way to do what I want or is it futile?

**Update:** As requested, I am adding a MWE.

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institution}
\date{}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section*{Outline}
         \begin{frame}
             \frametitle{Outline}
           \tableofcontents
         \end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\section{Section 2 \citep{ov11}}  %This works
\frame{
    \frametitle{A Sample Frame}}

\section{Section 3 \textcolor{Magenta}{\citep{ov11}}}  %This gives error

\bibliographystyle{apalike-url}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[{\"O}zsu and Valduriez, 2011]{ov11}
{\"O}zsu, M.~T. and Valduriez, P. (2011).
\newblock {\em Principles of Distributed Database Systems}.
\newblock Springer, 3rd edition.
\newblock Previous two editions of the book were published by Prentice-Hall in
  1991 and 1999, respectively.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `opaline` -- a document class? a LaTeX package? Please advise. Ideally, you would post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) to avoid any misunderstandings about what's going on, or any ambiguity about which additional packages need to be loaded to make your code work.

Comment: Mistype, sorry -- apalike is what I meant. It is a citation style. I can post a MWE, but it is really just what I posted, there is no other complication.

Comment: An MWE allows us to reproduce the error by copy-pasting. Right now, somebody who wants to help first has to figure out how to reproduce it. Then they can try to solve it. That means constructing bib entries, adding a suitable preamble, integrating your code, finishing the document.... An MWE should produce the error message you've posted. Moreover, the error message has information we can't use about e.g. the line number and context.

Comment: I just added an MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `\protect` the `\textcolor` command:

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institution}
\date{}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section*{Outline}
         \begin{frame}
             \frametitle{Outline}
           \tableofcontents
         \end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\section{Section 2 \citep{ov11}}  %This works
\frame{
    \frametitle{A Sample Frame}}

\section{Section 3 \protect\textcolor{Magenta}{\citep{ov11}}}  %This gives error

\bibliographystyle{apalike-url}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[{\"O}zsu and Valduriez, 2011]{ov11}
{\"O}zsu, M.~T. and Valduriez, P. (2011).
\newblock {\em Principles of Distributed Database Systems}.
\newblock Springer, 3rd edition.
\newblock Previous two editions of the book were published by Prentice-Hall in
  1991 and 1999, respectively.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]